# Eclipse auto-formatter, disable auto line-wrapping of comment lines

Tags: eclipse, autoformatting

I love eclipse auto formatting, but there's one feature that's driving me raging mad:

Since I use wrap-lines in my auto-formmatter, code like this:

```
private static Location                         _location           = null; // this is a comment
```

turns into horrible, horrible code like this:

```
private static Location                         _location           = null;                 // this
                                                                                                    // is
                                                                                                    // a
                                                                                                    // comment
```

this is not only painful to watch, but not at all convenient to change back...

Is there any way to remove line-wrapping for comments, or at least fix so it doesn't look like an absolute mess?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think that the thing you are specifically asking about you can achieve by editing your formatter:

- `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter`. There edit you click on `Edit...`
- If you are using the default Eclipse formatter you will need to edit the profile name (you cna not edit built in profile).
- Go to comments
- Deselect line comment formatting.

That way no formatting of comments of the type `//` will be done.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist anymore in the current version of Eclipse (4.14.0)

Comment: It still exists. "Format line comments" checkbox. Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent inline comments from being pushed down on the next line, so it's not much use actually.

Answer (score 2):

This annoys me also. To fix the wrapped comments you can use the keyboard shortcut CTL+ALT+J to join the comments onto one line. The comment-indicator characters (// or *) will still be there but at least it will save you some steps. Then you can just run a find and replace for the comment-indicators.