# Eclipse Not Wrapping Class Comments

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc

I hit Ctrl-Shift-F to auto-format.  The method comments get wrapped, but the class comments aren't getting wrapped.  Is there a setting to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really wanted was this:  Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Enable header comment formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645322/eclipse-auto-formatter-disable-auto-line-wrapping-of-comment-lines) explained, you find the Formatting Definitions in `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`. There edit you click on `Edit...`

If you want Word Wrapping (Line Wrapping) in Eclipse there is an solution delivered by an additional plugin: [word-wrap](http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/word-wrap/).